# TF-GAN tutorial by Google

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am studying the [tutorial on GANs by Google](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/gan/programming-exercise). In this notebook they have defined ***input_fn*** in which MNIST dataset is  loaded using tfds. I have generated my own dataset and have stored that in numpy array(shape : 4500, 512, 512).

I can't understand how ***input_fn*** works and how I can modify it so that I can input training data from my gdrive rather than downloading from tf datasets. I have noticed that ***input_fn*** is also used while training when ***gan_estimator.train*** is called. Can anyone explain how this function works?

Answer (score 0):

The function **input_fn** uses TensorFlow datasets in the following line to load MNIST.

```py
tfds.load('mnist', split=split)
               .map(_preprocess)
               .cache()
               .repeat()
```

You need to understand how TensorFlow datasets work to make one your own following the required structure to be processed.

You can get more information [here](https://medium.com/tensorflow/introducing-tensorflow-datasets-c7f01f7e19f3).